# Removing media file name under pictures in person report of Macfamilytree

Tags: naming, macfamilytree

How do I remove a media file name under pictures in a person report?

Filenames all different and some with huge names and I cannot find a way to remove it other then going to each file and deleting name.  With 290 people and 1-10 photos for each person that would take very very long.

I am using Macfamilytree Version 6.3.9

[image]

Comment: That is a very old version of the programme, it may be worth looking at an update to the current version 9 to see if this is an option in the current version.

Comment: not really answering my question though